# Are super and extends exclusive in generic wildcard?

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I am reading book for scjp preparation. I have read that `extends` in wild card is inclusive operator but `super` is exclusive.But I cannot find related example.  I tryed to write some code.

```
    List<? super Number> list1 = new ArrayList<Number>();
    List<? extends Number> list2= new ArrayList<Number>();
```

Both strings compiles good.

I am suppose that I knew something was wrong. Or maybe it is a book bug.

Please help to understand what was it in the book?

Comment: What do you mean by "inclusive" and "exclusive"?

Comment: What do you mean by "inclusive" and "exclusive" in this context? Both are "inclusive" in that the specified type itself is a valid type argument. Can you quote *exactly* what the book says?

Comment: It is termin from book. without explanation.

Comment: **Wildcards can be bounded. For example, <? extends Runnable> specifies that ? can match 
any type as long as it is Runnable or any of its derived types. Note that extends is inclusive, so 
you can replace X in ? extends X. However, in <? super Runnable> , ? would match only the 
super types of Runnable, and Runnable itself will not match (i.e., it is an exclusive clause).**

Comment: @Jon Skeet quote from book above

Comment: In that case, it's just the book being wrong. What's the book?

Comment: @Jon Skeet http://www.amazon.com/Certified-Professional-Programmer-1Z0-804-1Z0-805/dp/1430247649

Comment: @Jon Skeet This book has lot of bugs. Recently I have read that Arrays.asList doesn't work for primitives(compile error or exception)

Comment: It sounds like you should get a different book then :(

Comment: Can you advise something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in the book, both **super** and **extends** operators are inclusive - they accept the type defined in the wildcard. You can see this in both your example and in the following example

```
    List<? super Number> list1;
    list1 = new ArrayList<Number>();  // ok - inclusive
    list1 = new ArrayList<Object>();  // ok - wildcard accepts the super classes
    list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // compilation error

    List<? extends Number> list2;
    list2 = new ArrayList<Number>();  // ok - inclusive
    list2 = new ArrayList<Object>();  // compilation error
    list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // ok - wildcard accepts the subclasses
```